# Maximal ideal is prime -- proof: whats wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to prove that in a commutative ring (with unity), every maximal ideal is prime. I wrote the the following answer which was given wrong by my tutor. I dont understand whats wrong! (he says its obvious.) Can someone help me?

Proof:
Let $ab\in M$ and let if possible $a\not \in M$ and $b\not \in M$.

So $M\subsetneq <a> \neq R$ since $a\not \in M$ and $b\not\in <a>$.

Since $M$ is a maximal ideal and $<a> \neq R$, we must have $M=<a>$ and hence $a\in M$, which is a contradiction to the assumption.

Thus $M$ is a prime ideal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $a \notin M$ does not imply $M \subset \langle a\rangle$. All you can say is that $M \subsetneq \langle M,a\rangle$

Comment: I think you're confused about the definition of a maximal ideal. An ideal $I \subset A$ is maximal if any ideal $J \subseteq A$ containing $I$ is either $I$ or $A$. One way to look at this is that $I$ is *maximal* with respect to containment among proper ideals of $A$, hence the name. Here, you have $M$ such that $M$ is not contained in $\langle a \rangle$, yet you conclude that $M$ must equal $\langle a \rangle$...

Comment: But if $ab\in M$ and $a\not\in M$, then shouldn't it imply that $M$ is a proper subset of $<a>$?

Comment: No. Why would it imply that? Say $I = 2\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Then $I$ is maximal, and $3 \cdot 2 \in I$ and $3 \notin I$, but $I$ is certainly not a proper subset of $3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim, I am convinced with your example, but not able to relate with my arguments/notations! If you dont mind, could you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been answered in the comment of your misconception about "maximal ideal", and here is a possible way to prove what you wanted using your first step:

Let $\;M\le R\;$ be a maximal ideal and suppose $\;ab\in M\;$ and $\;b\notin M\;$ . This means $\;M\lneq M+bR\;$ so by maximality we get $\;M=M+bR \;$ or else $\;M+bR=R\;$ . The first option is imposible, otherwise

$$b=b\cdot1+0\in M\implies b\in M\;,\;\;\text{contradiction}$$

and thus it must be $\;M+bR=R\;$ , and this implies that there exist

$$m\in M\,,\,\,r\in R\;\;s.t.\;\;m+br=1\implies a=a\cdot 1=am +abr\in M+M=M$$

and thus $\;a\in M\;$ and we're done.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I have understood it now!